# Cleartool command performance: lshistory or find -exec

Tags: optimization, clearcase, cleartool

I am looking for query optimization, but IBM is not very chatty about that in the clearcase documentation.
So in short, we have quite big vob, and we would like to list all the change made between 2 dates, which query do you thing is the fastest, and do you see any improvement to be made ?

Method 1:

```
cleartool find -avobs -type f -element '(created_since(1-Jun-2016) &&                  !created_since(1-Sep-2016))
 && (Element_Type==""Program"" || Element_Type==""Output"" || Element_Type==""Data"")'
-ver 'created_since(1-Jun-2016) && !created_since(1-Sep-2016)' 
-exec 'cleartool describe -fmt ""#Name:%Xn Date:%Nd User:%u Label:%1.400Cl Attributes:%a Version:%Vn Comment:%Nc \n"" $CLEARCASE_XPN' 
>| test.txt
```

Method 2:

```
cleartool lshistory -avobs -since 1-Jun-2016 -fmt '#Name:%Xn Date:%Nd User:%u Label:%1.400Cl Attributes:%a Version:%Vn Comment:%Nc \n' -nco -pname >| test.txt
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`cleartool lshistory`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lshistory.htm) is about event records, the [minors ones can be scrubbed](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21239928). It offer less filtering options, which means you get everything and only then apply a filter yourself (`grep`)

Generally, a [`cleartool find`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm) can be faster, as you can add criteria to refine the search.

From "[Additional examples of the `cleartool find` command](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm)", in order to see all *changes* (not just creations at the element level, but changes, at the version level), the query is:

```
cleartool find . -version "{created_since(date1) && !created_since(date2)}"
```

-print

The fact that you can add:

- `type f` (you want only files, not folders)
- any other criteria (Note: I don't see "Element_Type" in [`query_language`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/query_language.htm))

Those will help to speed up the query.

---

The [OP M4hd1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6822607/m4hd1) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39478717/cleartool-command-performance-lshistory-or-find-exec/39478881#comment66296399_39478881):

Based on your comment I changed the query to that:

```
cleartool find -avobs -type f -element '(attr_sub(Element_Type,==,"Output"))' -ver 'created_since(1-Jun-2016) && !created_since(1-Sep-2016)' -exec 'cleartool describe -fmt ""#Name:%Xn Date:%Nd User:%u Label:%1.400Cl Attributes:%a Version:%Vn Comment:%Nc \n"" $CLEARCASE_XPN' >| test.txt
```

In multiple lines:

```
cleartool find -avobs -type f -element '(attr_sub(Element_Type,==,"Output"))' \
  -ver 'created_since(1-Jun-2016) && !created_since(1-Sep-2016)'  \
  -exec 'cleartool describe -fmt ""#Name:%Xn Date:%Nd User:%u Label:%1.400Cl Attributes:%a Version:%Vn Comment:%Nc \n"" $CLEARCASE_XPN' \
>| test.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Based on your comment I changed the query to that: cleartool find -avobs -type f -element '(attr_sub(Element_Type,==,"Output"))' -ver 'created_since(1-Jun-2016) && !created_since(1-Sep-2016)' 
-exec 'cleartool describe -fmt ""#Name:%Xn Date:%Nd User:%u Label:%1.400Cl Attributes:%a Version:%Vn Comment:%Nc \n"" $CLEARCASE_XPN' 
>| test.txt

Comment: @M4hd1 Well done! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.